# How to implement a module signature in OCaml with some default implementation?

Tags: ocaml

I want to implement a module signature in OCaml like below, where the function `get_data` depends on each module implementation and return an `option` type. I also want to provide the function `get_data_exn` which is a wrapping of `get_data` by un-optioning the result of `get_data`, and throwing an exception when the result returned by `get_data` is `None`

```
module type Foo = sig
  type t
  val get_data : int -> t option
  val get_data_exn : int -> t
end
```

In essence, the implementation of the function `get_data_exn` will be like below, and it will be the same for all modules that implement `Foo`:

```
let get_data_exn value = match get_data value with
  | Some data -> data
  | None -> raise DataNotFound
```

Is this possible for me to include this implementation of `get_data_exn` inside the signature `Foo` so that I don't have to repeat it for other modules? This is something similar to abstract class in Java.

Thank you for spending time to consider my question.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a core module type

```
module type Foo_core = sig
  type t
  val get_data: int -> t option
end
```

and extend it with a functor:

```
module Get_data_exn(Core:Foo_core) = struct
  let get_data_exn value = match Core.get_data value with
  | Some data -> data
  | None -> raise DataNotFound
end
```

Depending on your use case, it might be useful to expose a standard `Make_foo` functor

```
module Make_full_Foo(X:Foo_core) = struct
  include X
  include Get_data_exn(X)
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I understand your idea, although the module system becomes more complicated. Do you think if there is any simpler solution?

Comment: @TrungTa It is considered quite important in OCaml to keep code declaration "visible and traceable" to someone reading the code. Hence there is no way to make a declaration in your module implicit. Though they are frightening at first, functors are an awesome tool you should learn to be comfortable with.

Comment: @Trung Ta, there is a more complicated solution with classes and virtual methods, but the module system itself is very explicit by design.

Comment: @PatJ, octachron: Thanks for the clarification.